# wordpress theme option page create a select list (dropdown)?

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming, wordpress

How can i make a select list with 3 options in my WordPress theme options page with `<select>` ? I have never done this before. I tried this:

```
<p>
    <select name="wordpress_theme_options[background-position-x]" size="3">
      <option>Left</option>
      <option>Center</option>
      <option>Right</option>
    </select>
    <select name="wordpress_theme_options[background-position-y]" size="3">
      <option>Top</option>
      <option>Center</option>
      <option>Bottom</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

But I have no drop-down menu, it looks creepy and wont save the selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out (other example):

```
<p>
    <select name="wordpress_theme_options[slider-posts]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options['slider-posts'] ); ?>">
      <option value="value1" <?php selected( 'value1' == $options['slider-posts'] ); ?>>1</option>
      <option value="value2" <?php selected( 'value2' == $options['slider-posts'] ); ?>>2</option>
      <option value="value3" <?php selected( 'value3' == $options['slider-posts'] ); ?>>3</option>
      <option value="value4" <?php selected( 'value4' == $options['slider-posts'] ); ?>>4</option>
      <option value="value5" <?php selected( 'value5' == $options['slider-posts'] ); ?>>5</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. In order for the option to be selected when you reload the page, obviously it needs to have a property;

selected="selected"

But your code didn't do it for me. Changing each line from

<option value="value3" <?php selected( 'value3' == $options['slider-posts'] ); ?>>3</option>

To

<option value="value1" <?php if ( 'value1' == $options['slider-posts'] ) 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3</option>

Seemed to do the trick for me.